# Can't see menus at 768px mark

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my website responsive to all devices. Everything is going well except I have one problem.
When I hit the 768px width mark (tablets), I can't see my menu for this 1px. If, for instance, I'm at 769px I can easily see my menu bar.
And before the 768px mark, I have set my navbar to display a toggle button instead. The only issue I'm running on is that I can't see either my toggle or the menu bar. It disappears at this mark.

Here's the HTML code:

```
        <header class="l-header">
        <nav class="nav bd-grid">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="nav__logo">Alex Roarke</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
                <ul class="nav__list">
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#home" class="nav__link active">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#skills" class="nav__link">Skills</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#portfolio" class="nav__link">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#contact" class="nav__link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle">
                <i class='bx bx-menu'></i>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

And here's the CSS code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    
    .nav{
        height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem);
    }
    .nav__list{
        display: flex;
    }
    .nav__item{
        margin-left: var(--mb-4);
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .nav__toggle{
        display: none;
    }}
```

This is my website, alexroarke.com, where I'm testing my code. You can see the rest of the code from here. I'm learning to code right now and can easily understand what causes error but here, I'm clueless. Also, my javascript is working fine as it toggles the menu properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your media query to 768.9375px instead of 768px

*Edit: Sorry, I didn't realize that was what you wanted. In that case, I would do this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.nav__toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767.9375px)
.nav__menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: var(--header-height);
  right: -100%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
  transition: .5s;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Comment: It shows a toggle menu, which is better than nothing. But is there a way to show the menus instead? 768px is the size for an iPad and it's big enough to display menus easily. I think the toggle button doesn't suit well here. But it's better than before. @somdev

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Edited my answer!